# How to remove user role temporarily?

Tags: users, 9

I need to disable the "administrator" role from user accounts who log into my website from outside my network. For security, I only want users who have this role to be able to use it when they are on my network (determined by some custom PHP code I have).

I know I can remove a role from a user permanently using the appropriate entity methods like this:

```
<?php
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$user->removeRole('administrator');
$user->save();
```

But what about to do so temporarily, without updating the user permanently?

Looking at changes made to a user's roles in a custom module using `hook_user_login()` are permanent. In Drupal 7, I was able to achieve this by modifying the global `$user->roles` in various hooks.

I am also open to other ways Drupal allows me to meet my needs.

Comment: Possible use case for https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a Drupal 7 hook you can use the new AccountEvents::SET_USER event:

*/src/EventSubscriber/SetAccountSubscriber.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountEvents;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountSetEvent;
use Drupal\Core\Session\UserSession;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * mymodule event subscriber.
 */
class SetAccountSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Account set event handler.
   *
   * @param Drupal\Core\Session\AccountSetEvent $event
   *   Account set event.
   */
  public function onAccountSet(AccountSetEvent $event) {
    $account = $event->getAccount();
    if ($account->isAuthenticated()) {
      $roles = $account->getRoles();
      if (in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
        $roles = array_values(array_diff($roles, ['administrator']));
        $account = new UserSession([
          'uid' => $account->id(),
          'access' => $account->getLastAccessedTime(),
          'roles' => $roles,
          'name' => $account->getAccountName(),
          'preferred_langcode' => $account->getPreferredLangcode(),
          'preferred_admin_langcode' => $account->getPreferredAdminLangcode(),
          'mail' => $account->getEmail(),
          'timezone' => $account->getTimeZone(),
        ]);
        \Drupal::currentUser()->setAccount($account);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      AccountEvents::SET_USER => ['onAccountSet'],
    ];
  }

}
```

*mymodule.services.yml*

```
services:
  mymodule.set_account_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\SetAccountSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Be careful to avoid an infinite loop. The last line dispatches the event again and you need a condition preventing the line to be executed a second time, in this case through the removed role.